# wamp server 2.4 32 bit not turning online in windows 7 system and ERROR :1503

Tags: windows-7, wamp

I installed Wamp 2.4. the Apache is not working. the icon stays orange.i uninstalled Skype and  Google talk already in my system. I try run it as administrator, i checked the services.msc and try starting it but got ERROR:1503 and also checked the Apache error log. nothing's changed. the icon is still orange. what should i do